# search multiple channel IDs youtube/google API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

```
const channelIds = ['UCBi2mrWuNuyYy4gbM6fU18Q', 'UCshCsg1YVKli8yBai-wa78w', 'UCoMdktPbSTixAyNGwb-UYkQ']
        const online = await fetch(
            https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${channelIds}&type=video&eventType=live&key=key
        )
```

I am trying to search multiple Channels, but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The channelId parameter for search endpoint only accepts one channelId so you would have to make a separate requests for each channel.